# Dynamic wiremock to capture filter parameter and return in response

Tags: mocking, wiremock, wiremock-standalone, wiremock-record

I am trying to create dynamic mocks using WireMock. I have a situation where if I specify URL like

for this kind of request

```
/myManagement/v1/source?filters=myParty.id%3D%3D539%26myParty.role%3D%individual
```

what can I used so response will filter out the id and role and put in the response.

```
             {
                "id": "539",
                "href": "http://mypartyid/539,
                "name": "Employee",
                "role": "Customer",
                "validFor": {
                    "startDateTime": "2020-10-27T10:52:30.008Z"
                }
            }
```

I am using standalone wiremock jar 2.27.2 to create wiremock-server.

Comment: Try Wirespec. It's great for creating mock data using your own custom endpoints. It's free. https://wirespec.dev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your query parameters are not separated but are sent as a single parameter, you'll need to create a custom transformer to modify the response.

Read more about [transforming responses here.](http://wiremock.org/docs/extending-wiremock/#transforming-responses)